# Elastic Search Query for nested field type

Tags: elasticsearch, search, nested

I am trying to formulate a query for a business scenario where we have a nested field type named "types"(i.e like ArrayList of strings). Below are the sample indexed documents with "types" as one of the fields.

Document 1:
{   "types" : [
{
"Label" : "Dialog",
},
{
"Label" : "Violence",
},
{
"Label" : "Language",
}
}

Document 2:
{  "types" : [
{
"Label" : "Dialog",
}
}

Now, the requirement is that the search query should match at most one value within the field values i.e if a user searches for "Dialog", then it should return only Document 2 and not Document 1 because it has other values present in the field. Basically, it should only get those records that match exactly with the single search query value excluding all the other values present in the field.

**Below is the Mapping:**

```
{
  "media-hub-asset-metadata": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "true",
      "properties": {
        "Metadata": {
          "properties": {
            "Actors": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
                },
                "ngram": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer"
                }
              }
            },
            "Types": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "Acronym": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Display": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Label": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256,
                      "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
                    },
                    "ngram": {
                      "type": "text",
                      "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "TVLabel": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256,
                      "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
                    },
                    "ngram": {
                      "type": "text",
                      "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "MetadataType": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
            },
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        "Network": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Indexed Document:**

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 9139,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "media-hub-asset-metadata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1640655|VOD",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "AssetId" : 1640655,
          "MaterialId" : "XMX1311",
          "Metadata" : {
            "Actors" : [
              "Owen, Clive",
              "Mueller-Stahl, Armin",
              "Watts, Naomi"
            ],
            "AirDate" : "2013-05-01T00:00:00Z",
            "ClosedCaption" : true,
            "Code" : "",
            "Types" : [
              {
                "Label" : "Dialog",
                "TVLabel" : "D"
              },
              {
                "Label" : "Violence",
                "TVLabel" : "V"
              },
              {
                "Label" : "Language",
                "TVLabel" : "L"
              }
            ]
          },
          "MetadataType" : "VOD"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: You meant that the return will always contain those documents with only single object in the nested field ? 

Can you please bring more clarity to the question.

Comment: The query should return only those documents where the field value matches with the search query and the elemet size is one or there is only single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`script_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html) along with the [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

Try out this below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "types",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "types.Label": "Dialog"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "params._source.containsKey('types') && params._source['types'] != null && params._source.types.size() == 1 ? 1 : 0"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "min_score": 0.5             // note this
    }
  }
}
```

And search result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67594441",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.53899646,
        "_source": {
          "types": [
            {
              "Label": "Dialog"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Hi @EsCoder, sorry I haven't got any notification for your message.Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried your solution using the score, but I haven't got ay result using that.I get the below result

`{
  "took" : 98,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}`

Comment: @arjunbollam Can you try the same query by setting `min_score = 0.5` ? Updated the query in the answer as well, please try this and let me know if this works for you ?

Comment: @arjunbollam have you tried setting `min_score = 0.5` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried setting min_score to 0.5.But still it doesn’t give any results

Comment: @arjunbollam can you share the result of `{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "types",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "types.Label": "Dialog"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}` this query ?

Comment: Hi, here is the result.

`{
  "took" : 165,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}`

Comment: @arjunbollam Are you sure you have set `types` as of `nested` type ? As you are getting empty results in the nested query also, I believe there is some issue in the index mapping itself. Can you please share your index mapping as well ?

Comment: Hi @ESCoder, yes it is a nested field. I have updated the post with the index mapping.

Comment: @arjunbollam in your index mapping `Types` is the nested field (hope you have taken this field in the search query as well ), as in the answer I have considered `types` the `nested` field (note the upper and lower case)

Comment: @arjunbollam In your index mapping, the path of the `nested` field is `Metadata.Types`, and not just `Types`. Please change the path, and let me know what result you get ( Try to change the path on the same query which is given in the comments above)

Comment: @arjunbollam did you try changing the nested path in the search query?

Comment: Hi @EsCoder, Yes the nested path was correct right from the beginning. I gave you the example for convenience's sake.

Comment: @arjunbollam that's weird  Since you are not getting the results even for a simple Boolean query. Can you share some sample data having `types.Label: Dialog` ? Are you sure there is some document having this data ?

Comment: Hi @ESCoder, But I am getting the results when I remove the functions array and min_score from the search query.I have updated the post with the sample index documnet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232823/discussion-between-escoder-and-arjun-bollam).